# Non-hardware accelerated opacity

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In my webb app I need to fade out a smaller element. However, changing opacity of this element causes it to be hardware accelerated which in turn causes massive re-paints of different layers (instead of just one large paint) and I go from 9ms per frame to 20ms per frame.

Is there a way I can fade out an item without invoking hardware acceleration in Chrome?

Comment: Without at all being an expert in this area, isn't fading per definition changing the opacity of one layer over time so the layer beneath shows up instead?

Comment: Have you tried old `backface-visibility: hidden; perspective: 1000;` trick? That worked with 3d transforms.

Comment: @Locercus: Yes, however in this case the hardware acceleration causes lots of redundant layers and repaints.

Comment: @skobaljic: No, could you explain a bit more about what that does? Doesn't that force hardware acceleration?

Comment: I don't know what it does to webkit browsers, but it solved some problems before it had with rendering - just try it, no cost.